# Qt 5.1 Beta Error using std::atomic c++11 feature

Tags: c++, macos, qt, c++11, clang

I have just started to work with QT and am still getting familiar with the compilation process. Currently, I am trying to port an existing QT project to Mac. This app compiles and runs on Linux and Windows.

When I compile the project on Mac OSX 10.8.2 , I am getting this c++11 related error ,

```
#include ../xxx/pch.h:71:10: fatal error: 'atomic' file not found
#include <atomic>
^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [debug/xxx/objective-c++.pch] Error 1
make: *** [debug] Error 2
11:32:01: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project xxx (kit: Qt5.1.0)
When executing step 'Make'
```

I have included the below flags in the.pro file to enable c++11 ,

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

CONFIG += c++11
```

I am building the project with the pre-built QT5.1Beta package (Clang) which I believe has c++11 enabled.

I see the atomic header in the below locations
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/atomic
and in /usr/lib/c++/v1/atomic

I tried testing by including the complete path ,
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr//lib/c++/v1/atomic

I am getting the below error,

```
In file included from ../xxx/pch.h:71:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/atomic:535:2: 
error: atomic is not implemented

In file included from ../xxx/pch.h:124:
../../../yyy.h:308:12: error: no type named 'atomic' in namespace 'std'
std::atomic<bool> m_signaled;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which compiler version and standard library version are you trying to use?  ie which do you have installed?

Comment: I use clang to build the project. I have the latest version of Xcode 4.6.2 and the command line tools installed. $ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
Thread model: posix

Comment: I use QT Creator to build the project. Compiler used is Clang which you get by installing Xcode command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Add also

```
macx:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: I tried adding these flags and I am still getting the same error. Additional Note:
The project I am compiling has over 50 cpp source files. I tested with a simple sample application. I am trying to figure out the difference.
I get this error only when including <atomic> from a pre-compiled header.
---------- pch.h ---------
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

//Qt
#include <QtGui>

#include <atomic>
#endif
------------------------

When "#include <atomic>" is added directly to the cpp source file, the sample app compiles and runs without errors.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is a bit late, but I fixed it using the `-std=gnu++0x` flag

Comment: or `-std=c++11`