# root/include/Rtypes.h:38:10: fatal error: 'atomic' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

I have seen that there are other questions concerning the problem of "fatal error: 'atomic' file not found", but unfortunately in noone I found a solution that works for me.

So I explain the problem: I am using a mac-os-x environment, I am a new user of mac. I need to compile a C++ code, named 'ASICs_Analysis' with a makefile. In the code I use root framework version 5.34/34.
When I try to compile using the command "make", I obtain this error:

```
 In file included from /Users/danieleninci/IFAE/software/root/include/TObject.h:31:
 /Users/danieleninci/IFAE/software/root/include/Rtypes.h:38:10: fatal error: 'atomic' file not found
 #include <atomic>
     ^
 1 error generated.
 make: *** [ASICs_Analysis] Error 1
```

I include the 'atomic' file in the code but I have the same error.
The makefile I am using is this:

```
CXX = $(shell root-config --cxx)
CXXFLAGS = $(shell root-config --cflags) -std=c++11
LDFLAGS = $(shell root-config --libs) -L$(ROOTSYS)/lib
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
TARGET = ASICs_Analysis

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SOURCES)
         $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
         rm $(TARGET)
```

I tried to follow what was proposed in [Qt 5.1 Beta Error using std::atomic c++11 feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782776/qt-5-1-beta-error-using-stdatomic-c11-feature) , but it does not work for me.

Other info about the compiler installed:

```
gcc: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
clang: Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
       Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
       Thread model: posix
Xcode: 4.6
```

I don't know with what this error could be related, maybe with the compiler? What is it going wrong?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The compiler and your IDE are very old, and might not be fully C++11 conformant.

Comment: XCode 4.6 is ancient (it's almost exactly three years old) and doesn\t have full support for C++11. If you need to use an old machine, you can install a newer gcc or clang through macports or homebrew.